# Power BI Embedded + Javascript API Report Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, powerbi-embedded

I'm attempting to extend Power BI's "App Owns Data" example to use some Javascript filtering. The code I've added is below. I'm getting a critical Javascript syntax error on line 86, which is the blank line following "filters.push(Filter1);"

```
var Filter1 = {
    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#advanced",
    target: {
        table: "PBI Load",
        column: "Business Unit"
    },
    logicalOperator: "OR",
    conditions: [
        {
            operator: "Contains",
            value: "Information"
        }
    ]
}

report.on('loaded', event => {
    report.getFilters()
        .then(filters => {

            filters.push(Filter1);

            return report.setFilters(filters);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

getFilters() might not give you a mutable copy for the report filters.
try copying to a local variable and resetting the new array (after the addition) with setFilters().

in addition, to verify your custom filter is valid, I would suggest the following test:
1. set the filter in Power BI or in your application via the UI (filter pane to the right)
2. run getFilters()
3. see the filter you've set and verify against your custom-made one to see if it's the same.